# react router - how to render Link from content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do I render react-router Link component from a paragraph with contents?
It might be at random position and I don't find handly sperating `content` param to beforeText, link and afterText object

Let's say I'm building a blog where the blog-post section is passing content with some url's to the text rendering component and it be Link to internal app route (or might be not, just plain text)

```
  class ParentComponent extends Component{
    render(){
      <Content content='Lorem ... <Link to="/page">Some link</Link> lorem ipsum ...'
    }
  }


  class Content extends Component {
     const { content } = this.props
     render(){
       <div className="text-section">
         {content}
       </div>
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this.props.children for passing nested components so that they can be rendered straight forward. Your code should then look like this:

```
 class ParentComponents extends Component{
     render(){
         <Content>
          <p>Lorem ...<Link to="/page">Some link</Link>lorem ipsum</p>
         </Content> 
     }
 }


class Content extends Component {
    render(){
        <div className="text-section">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
```

}

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Can you provide a snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Question is that he has content in DB or variable like x = "<p>hello<a href='some -link'>world</a>!</p>"; now he wants to render x as react component and <a> to be a Router link, so if it is linked to react page, it can load as SPA.